# Given $|f(z)|<|g(z)|$ on some domain and both are analytic, prove that f(z)/g(z) is analytic.

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

This seems to be obvious because whenever $g(z)=0$, $f(z)$ is also 0. I think this can be proved using Caucy Estimates. But I'd like to see if there is some other ways/easier way to do this.

Comment: $g$ can never be $0.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $D$ be the domain of $f$ and $g$ and let $Z=g^{-1}(0)$. I will assume that $g$ is not the null function. The  set$Z$ is a discrete subset of $D$ and $\frac fg\colon D\setminus Z\longrightarrow\mathbb C$ is analytic, since it is the quotient of two analytic functions. Besides, $\frac fg$ is bounded near each point of $Z$ and therefore, by [Riemann's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann's_theorem), you can extend it to an analytic function from $D$ into $\mathbb C$.

Comment: I understand the "bounded near points in Z" argument. But just to make sure I understand its precise meaning: to use Riemann's theorem, we just have to find a sequence of points converge to $Z$ and each one of them (not including the limiting point in $Z$) is smaller than some $M$. Is this understanding accurate?

Comment: @DanielLi No. ALl you need is to prove that ther is a neighborhood $N(\subset D)$ of $z(\in Z)$ such that the restriction of $\frac fg$ to $N\setminus\{z\}$ is bounded. But the whole function $\frac fg$ is bounded! You have $\left|\frac fg\right|<1$.

Comment: $N$ does not include $z$ right?

Comment: @DanielLi It does. I've edited my previous comment. I meant that the restriction of $\frac fg$ to $N\setminus\{z\}$ is bounded.

Comment: Thank you sir. This is very clear!

Answer (score 0):

Let $D$ be the domain. Since $g(z)$ can never be $0$ in $D,$ (otherwise we would have $0\le |f(z)| <0$ for some $z\in D,$ contradiction), it is elementary that $f(z)/g(z)$ is analytic in $D.$